# Blue Skies in Gazebo 1.9

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've successfully gotten the Gazebo 1.9/ROS Hydro to work on multiple computers (on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10), but when the Gazebo simulator pops up, the sky is just a light gray. I see in the screenshot that it's supposed to be blue with clouds - any idea what I'm missing in my installation?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6459/blue-skies-in-gazebo-1.9/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

your is not the problem. The sky is just optional and has to be enabled explicitly.

gazebo world files can contain a scene/sky block like:

```
<scene>
  <sky>
    <clouds>
      <speed>12</speed>
    </clouds>
  </sky>
</scene>
```

This enables SkyX...(taken from `empty_sky.world` example)
have a look at the corresponding SDF regions for more information
[sdf1.5 sky](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=scene#scene_sky)

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-07**:
Cool!  Thanks for this answer!  Is there a way to make the sky red instead of blue?  I played with the color values inside the scene tag and I could get the ground to turn red, but the sky remained blue.  Changing the ambient values inside the cloud tag didn't seem to have any effect.  I'm using Gazebo 1.9.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-07-07**:
There currently isn't a hook to change the sky color and still have clouds. Please submit an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new) to have this feature added to Gazebo.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-08**:
Done.  Thanks.  Is there a way today in Gazebo 1.9 to change the sky color without clouds?  Just wondering due to the wording in your comment above.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-07-09**:
You could try the  [SDF tag](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.4.html#background58).

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-07-11**:
thanks for the help!

**Comment by [hal9000](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1047/hal9000/) on 2015-03-19**:
I'm having trouble with the sdf1.4 sky link in your answer above. Has this URL moved?  Also, If I wanted to paint a real sun in the sky, where in the code should I start?  Thanks!

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2015-06-10**:
Hi, the URL moved... sdf specification can now be found under [www.sdformat.org](http://www.sdformat.org)
I updated the url...